# Real one page example on ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

Today there are many talks about one page ajax ui (like facebook, twitter etc) and mvc team declared that they are going to make it easy in MVC4 accourding to roadmap, but half of year past and i still haven't seen even one example. Even if we talk about ajax in mvc mvc there isn't much more official best practise examples (exept this one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs). So have anyone know any information about what are they going to do and how should we do it right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally believe that they have already made it easier from day one by releasing asp.net mvc into the world. The other companion to making those calls easier is to use jQuery.

I think it's as simple as following 3 steps.

1. Expose a JsonResult controller method
2. Call the jQuery.getJSON() method to the controller method, decide on whether you want to append or clear out the div that you will be putting the results in
3. Enjoy all the goodness

The ease of use comes from the fact that ASP.NET MVC is as close to the markup as you want to get and using client side libraries is made easier.

ASP.NET 4.0 with predictive client id's also now makes using client side libraries a lot easier.